# Trying to convert flat yaml file into hashmap in java using jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to convert a flat yaml file which looks like this

```
aramex: "Aramex"
aramex_cash_on_delivery: "Aramex COD"
australia_post: "Australia Post"
boxberry_delivery: "Boxberry Delivery"
boxberry_locker: "Boxberry Pickup and Postamats"
boxit_delivery: "BoxIt Home Delivery"
boxit_locker: "BoxIt Locker & Store Pickup"
chronopost: "Chronopost"
```

into a hashmap so I can access it from the keys directly without having to to maintain additional files.

such as:

```
map.get("aramex"); // should return "Aramex"
```

I would prefer if I didn't have to add properties to a pojo because that is more maintenance for me.  Any example of how this would be done with jackson?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a yaml file like this:

```
shipping_options:
  aramex: "Aramex"
  aramex_cash_on_delivery: "Aramex COD"
  australia_post: "Australia Post"
  boxberry_delivery: "Boxberry Delivery"
  boxberry_locker: "Boxberry Pickup and Postamats"
```

A pojo like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ShippingOptions {
  @JsonProperty("shipping_options")
  Map<String, String> shippingOptions;
}
```

And code to get the key:

```
public static String getShippingOptionValue(String key) throws IOException {
    String baseDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String filePath = baseDir + "/src/test/resources/shippingoptions.yaml";
    File yaml = new File(filePath);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    ShippingOptions shippingOptions = null;
    try {
      shippingOptions = mapper.readValue(yaml, ShippingOptions.class);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      log.info("file could not be found {}", filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.info("could not load shipping options from {}", filePath);
      throw new IOException("shipping options YAML file was unable to be converted by Jackson {}", e);
    }
    assert shippingOptions != null;
    String value = shippingOptions.getShippingOptions().get(key);
    log.info("Shipping option retrieved was {}", value);
  }
```

Hope that helps someone.